# How to response send using react,redux,axios to action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I want to get response that is returned from post to payload. How do I send the result that is returned to action.How can I do this ?

```
import axios from 'axios';
import * as types from './actionTypes';

const ROOT_URL = `http://localhost:8000`;

export function addPost(title){
    const url = `${ROOT_URL}/api/v1/post/`;
    var request;

    axios.post(url, {
        title: title,
    }).then(function (response) {
        request = response;
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
        request = response;
    });

    console.log(request);

    return {
        type:types.ADD_POST,
        payload:request
    }
}
```

Comment: Super helpful: http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to have a separate service which calls the appropriate action:

Something like

```
export function addPost(title){
    return {
        type:types.ADD_POST,
        payload:request
    }
}

export function addPostService(title){
    const url = `${ROOT_URL}/api/v1/post/`;
    var request;

    axios.post(url, {
        title: title,
    }).then(function (response) {
        dispatch(addPost(response.body))
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
        request = response;
    });
}
```

If you want a more advanced solution, check out redux-thunk: https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk